# How to split date range to time interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

By selecting the range of data I can check how many items is in the selected range.

Now these tasks I need to split into time intervals - according to the calendar interval (15 minutes) - in order to verify is there 2 events next to each other. If there is 2 events in this same time interval (Event 1 and Event 2) user should not be able to select this interval.

How to do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/LFAzB/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        allDaySlot: false,
        scrollTime: '10:00:00',
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        minTime: '06:45:00',
        maxTime: '23:15:00',
        eventDurationEditable: true,
        eventStartEditable: true,

        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event 1',
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T10:30:00',
                end: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T10:45:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 2',
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T10:30:00',
                end: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T10:45:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Longer Event',
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T12:30:00',
                end: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T13:45:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T13:45:00',
                end: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + 'T14:00:00'
            }
        ],
        select: function(start, end) {
            console.log( 'Events :' + getEventsByTime( start, end ).length );
            console.log( getEventsByTime( start, end ) );
        }
    });

});


function getEventsByTime( start, stop ) {
    var todaysEvents = $('div[name=calendar]').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {

       return ( 
           ( event.start >= start && event.end <= stop ) || 
           ( start >= event.start && stop <= event.end)  || 
           (start <= event.start && stop >= event.start) ||
           (start >= event.start && start <= event.end)
       );
    });
    return todaysEvents;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. Her's solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/LFAzB/5/

```
select: function(start, end) {
    console.log( 'Events :' + getEventsByTime( start, end ).length );
    var ev = getEventsByTime( start, end );
    console.log( ev );
    var itms = {};            

    ev.forEach(function(entry){

      var begin = moment(entry.start);
      var final = moment(entry.end);


    while( begin.diff(final) < 0 ) {
        itms[begin] =  ( itms[begin] || 0) + 1;
        if( itms[begin] >= maxEventsInInterval ) {
            console.log(' __ WARNING __ , max events exceeded! ');
        }

        begin = moment(begin).add('seconds', 900);
    }

});
    console.log( itms );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function takes start_date and end_date as required arguments which will be in date Object,
and the optional arguments(day interval:dy_inv, hour interval:hr_inv, minute interval:min_inv) will be on which and what value of interval to split the Range.
By default it will split by 1 day

```
function get_date_intervals(start_date, end_date, dy_inv=1, hr_inv=0, min_inv=0){
    var date_intervals = [];
        
    if (dy_inv == 0 && hr_inv == 0 && min_inv == 0){
        dy_inv = 1
    }

    sd = start_date
    while(sd < end_date){
        date_interval = [];
        date_interval.push(sd)

        let ed = new Date(sd.getFullYear(), sd.getMonth(), sd.getDate()+dy_inv, sd.getHours()+hr_inv, sd.getMinutes()+min_inv)
    
        if (ed >= end_date){
            ed = end_date
        }
        
        date_interval.push(ed)
        date_intervals.push(date_interval);

        sd = new Date(ed.getFullYear(), ed.getMonth(), ed.getDate(), ed.getHours(), ed.getMinutes()+1)
    }

    return date_intervals
}



// below is the example of function call, 
// Note: month will start from 0, i.e., Jan-0, Feb-1, Mar-2

// get_date_intervals(new Date(from_yr, from_mon-1, from_dy, from_hr, from_min), new Date(to_yr, to_mon-1, to_dy, to_hr, to_min), 0, 1, 0)
get_date_intervals(new Date(2022, 1-1, 1, 10, 5), new Date(2022, 3-1, 10, 5, 10), 0, 1, 0)
```